# Use css to make line under text width the same for all on mobile view

Tags: html, css

I want to line under the text to be the same size width for all. It needs to be uniform width (same size). The line under the 'press' and 'phone' needs to have the same width as the 'questions' line. Here is

[image]

I've tried adjusting the width, but nothing so far.

```css
.contact-banner {
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.contacts-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 2%;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: var(--elewa-group-website-dmsans-regular);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 550;
}

p {
  margin: 5% 0;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180, 175, 175);
}

h2 {
  font-family: var(--elewa-group-website-dmsans-regular);
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: .4;
}

p {
  font-family: var(--elewa-group-website-dmsans-regular);
  font-size: 27px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .banner-main {
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  .contacts-info {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .questions-info,
  .press-info,
  .phone-info {
    margin: 5% 0;
  }
  .press-info,
  .phone-info {
    padding-top: 2%;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 5% 0;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180, 175, 175);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .banner-main {
    margin-top: 4%;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 5% 0;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180, 175, 175);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-banner">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
  <div class="contacts-info">
    <div class="questions-info">
      <h2 class="subheader">Questions</h2>
      <p>Info@elewagroup.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="press-info">
      <h2 class="subheader">Press</h2>
      <p>Press@elewa.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="phone-info">
      <h2 class="subheader">Phone</h2>
      <p>+254 78 92 27 755</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the same width, set the border-bottom on the parent div instead of the p tag like so :

```css
.questions-info{
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180, 175, 175);
}
.press-info{
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180, 175, 175);
}

.phone-info{
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180, 175, 175);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stretch the flex children and align text to center for them and the wrapper element. Also use `inline-flex` on the inner container.

```css
.contact-banner {
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.contacts-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 2%;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: var(--elewa-group-website-dmsans-regular);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 550;
}

p {
  margin: 5% 0;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180, 175, 175);
}

h2 {
  font-family: var(--elewa-group-website-dmsans-regular);
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: .4;
}

p {
  font-family: var(--elewa-group-website-dmsans-regular);
  font-size: 27px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .banner-main {
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  .contacts-info {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .questions-info,
  .press-info,
  .phone-info {
    margin: 5% 0;
  }
  .press-info,
  .phone-info {
    padding-top: 2%;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 5% 0;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180, 175, 175);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .banner-main {
    margin-top: 4%;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 5% 0;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180, 175, 175);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-banner">
  <h1>Contact</h1>

  <div class="contacts-info">
    <div class="questions-info">
      <h2 class="subheader">Questions</h2>
      <p>Info@elewagroup.com</p>
    </div>

    <div class="press-info">
      <h2 class="subheader">Press</h2>
      <p>Press@elewa.com</p>
    </div>

    <div class="phone-info">
      <h2 class="subheader">Phone</h2>
      <p>+254 78 92 27 755</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```